# Getting white space after adding elements

Tags: html, css

Adding elements to my page (like footer, imgs, etc.) I keep getting white space added to the bottom of my page. What causes it and how can I fix it?

## EDIT: changed some parts. Thanks to anyone who edited post for me.

```css
body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
#stajl ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
}
#stajl ul li:hover a {
    background-color: #99bbff;
}
#stajl ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#stajl ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #80aaff;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
#stajl ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -105px;
}
#stajl ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
#stajl ul ul li {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    width: 352px;
}
#stajl ul ul li a {
    color: #52527a;
}
#stajl ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #1f1f2e;
}
.arrow {
    font-size: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#img img {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#header {
    text-align: center;
}
#header h1 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -40px;
    left: -60px;
    color: #99ccff;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
#bkd {
    z-index: -1;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -9px;
    top: -99px;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
#bkd img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
#foot-wrap {
    margin: -9px;
}
#footer {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    opacity: 0.9;
    position: relative;
    top: -150px;
    height: 192px;
}
#footer a img {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
}
#childs a:first-child {
    right: -30px;
    position: relative;
    top: -160px;
    left: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#footer h2 {
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    font-family: Verdana;
    color: #668cff;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 80px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#footer ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#footer ul li {
    position: relative;
    top: -19px;
    padding-bottom: 19px;
    left: 35px;
    font-family: cursive;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#footer a:nth-child(2) {
    right: -30px;
    position: relative;
    top: -120px;
    left: 120px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#footer a:nth-child(3) {
    right: -30px;
    position: relative;
    top: -80px;
    left: 90px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.prvi {
    position: relative;
    font-family: Verdana;
    color: #668cff;
    top: -342px;
    left: 400px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Potts Financial Services</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style2.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="stajl">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Home Page </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Services <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Trades </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Exchanges </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Business to Business </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact </a>
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="img">
            <a href="#"><img src="pfslogo2.png" /> </a>
        </div>
        <div id="header">
            <h1>We're here to help! </h1>
        </div>
        <div id="bkd">
            <img src="debtbackground.jpg" />
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div id="foot-wrap">
                <div id="footer">
                    <h2 class="h2"> Social </h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Twitter</li>
                        <li>Facebok</li>
                        <li>Youtube</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div id="childs">
                        <a href="www.twitter.com">
                            <img src="twitter.png" />
                        </a>
                        <a href="www.facebook.com">
                            <img src="facebook.png" />
                        </a>
                        <a href="www.youtube.com">
                            <img src="youtube.png" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h2 class="prvi">Contact</h2>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Some pictures:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please, be more clear.

Comment: That's not a valid HTML.

Comment: I made screenshots. Hope it helps. I am new here so don't know much. Sorry !

Comment: @Vuks Do you have a live place where we can see and try?

Comment: @Vuks You are missing a closing `</li>` tag in your list.

Comment: I only use Skype, so would that be okay? :)

Comment: @TylerH I belive `<li>something<li>next thign` will make browser to see it as `<li>something</li><li>next thign`. End tag is optional for lists.

Comment: @Vuks I have solved. Kindly check the answer below.

Comment: @PraveenKumar We don't know the doctype so we can't make that assumption, and also for consistency's sake, it should be added; all the other `<li>` elements have closing tags.

Comment: @TylerH Rightly said. `:)`

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> it is. 
I haven't added that because last time I did I couldn't show you code very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the `left` here:

```css
#footer ul li {
    position: relative;
    top: -19px;
    padding-bottom: 19px;
    left: 35px;
    font-family: cursive;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

If you give a `width` there it will fix. So, give this:

```css
#footer ul li {
    position: relative;
    top: -19px;
    padding-bottom: 19px;
    left: 35px;
    width: 50%;
    font-family: cursive;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**Output: http://output.jsbin.com/wivecepuho**

Comment: Hope you can find out what's going on, because I tried many things already, but I wasn't smart enough to figure out, what's going on.
EDIT: I have used only once position:absolute as I can see. I used many times position:relative though.

Comment: @Vuks Whole layout is very wrong. You shouldn't use `position` at all.

Comment: @Vuks That's **wrong**, or **crime**. See other websites. You need to use `float` or `overflow`. You should never use `position`.